# Reporting services project stored procedure as dataprovider for a dropdown

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services

Is it possible to let the dataprovider of a combobox be a stored procedure?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming you are using  reportbuilder 3.0 it is. All you do is setup a new datasource and set the query type to Stored Procedure. You then set the available values to the output of that data source.

I cant comment on other versions as I have not used them

Comment: But it is possible to add a dropdown that is populated with data from a stored procedure? Then a user can choose something in the dropdown and hit View Report.

Comment: That is what I just described. You set the available values for the parameter to the output of the datasource that is based on your stored procedure. The parameter will then have a dropdown box style allowing the user to select a value from your list